# How to read value a particular cell of a text file in a batch file?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, automation

I've a text file with 10 rows and 5 columns. I want to read every value through a batch file.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: What format is the text file? CSV? TSV?

Comment: He tagged the question CSV

Answer (score 0):

File fivecolumns.txt:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

File fivecolumns.cmd:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims=," %%a in (fivecolumns.txt) do echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d, %%e
```

Your values for each row will be in `%%a`, `%%b`, `%%c`, `%%d`, and `%%e` each  time through the `FOR` loop - you'd, of course, probably want to do something more interesting than just echo them back out again.